# Searching JSON with PHP

Tags: php, json

I grab a load of JSON data which i decode using php json_decode. I want to search or extract certain elements of the JSON object. I've looked at a few similar examples with little success.

The JSON structure is like this. I want to extract the stock element to compare, using PHP.

```
{
"items":{
         "item000":{
            "color":"black",
            "skuId":"sku000",
            "price":{
               "sku000":"139.99"
            },
            "name":"item Name",
            "stock":"in stock"
         }
}
```

Comment: It should be `$json['items']['item000']['stock']` after it's been parsed (assuming `$json = json_decode('...');`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) if you use something as:

```
$decodedArray = json_decode($jsonString,true);
```

And according to your example to access the stock value you will need:

```
foreach($decodedArray['items'] as $itemKey=>$itemProps)
{
  echo $itemProps['stock'];
}
```

And as I tested it, your json is invalid. You must add one more curly bracket add the end of your json to close the main root object :)